# Stability of equilibrium

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-theory

Consider the following PDE system:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+fv-g(\frac{\partial (H+h)}{\partial x}),\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-fu-g(\frac{\partial (H+h)}{\partial y}),\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial uH}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial vH}{\partial y},
$$
with functions

- $u(x,y,t), v(x,y,t)$ (=velocity in the $x$-, $y$-direction)
- $H(x,y,t)$ (=depth of fluid)
- $h(x,y)$ (=surface of the bottom)

and parameter $f\in\mathbb{R}$, gravitational acceleration $g$.

Assume $h$ and $H_0$ to be constant. Then $E=(0,0,H_0)^T$ is an equilibrium.

The question is whether this equilibrium is stable with respect to wave perturbations. To this end linearize the system in $E$ and insert solutions of the form
$$
(u,v,H)^T=e^{i(kx+ly)+\lambda t}\cdot (u_0,v_0,z_0)^T.
$$

This yields
$$
\lambda \eta = A(k,l)\eta,~~~\text{ where }A(k,l)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & f & -gik\\-f & 0 & -gil\\-H_0ik & -H_0il & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \eta=(u,v,H).
$$

Hence, $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A(k,l)$. This gives the dispersion relation
$\lambda=\lambda(k,l)$ to be
$$
 \lambda (\lambda^2+gH_0(k^2+l^2)+f^2)=0
$$
having for $k,l\in\mathbb{R}$ solutions
$$
\lambda=0,~~\lambda=\pm i\sqrt{gH_0(k^2+l^2)+f^2}
$$

**I have some questions to this.**

(1) This is the computation of the point spectrum of the linear operator $A(k,l)$, isn't it?

(2) It is said that $E$ is stable if $Re(\lambda(k,l))\leq 0$. Up to this, it would be stable for $f\in\mathbb{R}, g,H_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$ since the computed eigenvalues have zero real part then. The condition $Re(\lambda(k,l))\leq 0$ for stability is strange to me: I always thought that the eigenvalues have to live in the left half-side(i.e. Re <0) to have stability with respect to the point spectrum?

(3) What is with the essential spectrum here? I guess $A(k,l)$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{C}^3$ to itself and hence a linear operator on a finite dim. space, hence its spectrum only consists of the point spectrum?

(4) Why are solutions of the form
$(u,v,H)^T=e^{i(kx+ly)+\lambda t}\cdot (u_0,v_0,z_0)^T$ called *linear* wave-solutions: What is linear about them? - Or are they only called linear waves since we insert them in a linear system?

(5) Is there a special reason why we insert solutions of the form 
$(u,v,H)^T=e^{i(kx+ly)+\lambda t}\cdot (u_0,v_0,z_0)^T$ and not solutions of the form

$$
(u,v,H)^T=e^{i(kx+ly-\lambda t)}\cdot (u_0,v_0,z_0)^T
$$
which would be the typical 2D-plane wave ansatz?

Comment: Interesting. I was going through non-commutative rings today and on one of my diagrams I saw similar matrix like the one above with the exception that I would give $gik$ and $gil$ positive values. Before I could proceed to the discussion, I found it necessary first to assert that my principles are in themselves sufficient for the hint or answer.